# javascript image swap affects too many images

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, thumbnails

ive got a collection of 3 images, two small one large.  id like to to be set up so when you click on a small image, it takes the place of the larger one.  The issue is that I have a collection of three of these three images so when you click on a small image, it takes the spot of all three large images.  Any suggestions for getting it so it only takes the spot of the large image in its section?  Heres some code.  Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('img').click(function(){
        var url = $(this).attr('src');
        $(this).parents('.picture-container').find('.large-picture > img').attr('src', url);
        $('.large-picture > img').attr('src', url);
        $(this).attr('src', bigUrl);
        });
        });
```

picture section (there are three of these)

```
   <div class = 'picture-container'>
        <div class = 'large-picture' style = 'width:50%;height:100%;float:left;'>
            <img src = 'close_table_dupontstudios.png' width = '100%' height = '100%'>
        </div>
        <div class = 'picture-content' style = 'float:right;width:45%;height:100%;'>
            <div class='picture-title'>BOUTIQUE PRODUCTION STUDIO</div>
            <div class='picture-text'>We built a boutique full service production studio that allows for one, two and three person filmed interviews and conversations. We have studio lights, a three camera set-up and remote monitoring. Additionally, our Infinity Wall creates a clean and professional look that allows the film to be about the message.</div>
            <div class = 'small-picture-wrapper'>
                <div class = 'small-picture' style = 'float:left;height:100%;'>
                    <img src = 'hair_and_makeup_dupontstudios.png' width = '100%' height = '100%'>
                </div>
                <div class = 'small-picture' style = 'float:right;height:100%;'>
                    <img src = 'infinity_wall_dupontstudios.png' width = '100%' height = '100%'>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of jquery slideshow/carousel [plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/?s=carousel) that should do what you need.

If you need a snippet to just do this one thing, you might need to clarify what you want.

From what I gather, there should only be 3 images at any time. One is large, the other two are small ( like thumbnails? ). You want to click on a small image and have it replace the large image ( so the small image becomes as large as the large image and takes it's position?).

DOes the large image then shrink and take the place of the image just selected.

Just explain it like you would to a little kid.

Comment: you've got it exactly right.  the clicked-on small image takes the place of the large one and the large one takes the place of hte clicked-on small one.  However, there are three sections of these and I'd like it to be where clicking on a small image in a section will take the large image of the same section, not all of them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I changed anything in the html other than the img src's, so this should work:

```
 <script>

       $(document).ready( function(){

          $(".small-picture > img").click( function(){ 

              var small_img = $(this);
              var small_img_src = small_img.attr("src"); 

              var img_container = small_img.closest(".picture-container");

              var large_img = img_container.find(".large-picture > img");
              var large_img_src = large_img.attr("src");

              large_img.attr("src", small_img_src);
              small_img.attr("src", large_img_src);

         });
     });


    </script>
```